# How do I get the selected row in Gridview in Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

Let me elaborate ... below is my partial gridview with a button field ... what I want is the text value of the button to use in building a url:

```
<asp:GridView CssClass="gridUser" ID="UsersGrid" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanging="PageIndexChange" OnRowCommand="Paging" OnSorting="SortPage" OnRowCreated="RowCreated"
                AutoGenerateColumns="false">

                <PagerSettings Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" FirstPageImageUrl="~/Images/Navigation/firstpageIcon.png" LastPageImageUrl="~/Images/Navigation/lastpageIcon.png"
                    NextPageImageUrl="~/Images/Navigation/forwardOneIcon.png" PreviousPageImageUrl="~/Images/Navigation/backOneIcon.png" Position="Bottom" />

                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Name" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridHeader">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:Button ID="UserLink" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UserName") %>' CssClass="linkButton" OnClientClick = "return GetSelectedRow(this)"></asp:Button>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

and here is my javascript :

```
 $(".linkButton").click(function () {
        var ul = document.getElementById('UserLink');
        var row = ul.parentNode.parentNode;
        var rowIndex = row.rowIndex - 1;
        var Userid = row.cells[0].childNodes[1].value;
        var User = Userid;
        alert("Row is : " + row + "RowIndex is : " + rowIndex + "User ID is " + User);
    });
```

My issue is that my row returned is the first row ... not the selected row ... how do I get the selected row? Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this... Change naming conventions according to your requirement

```js
<script type = "text/javascript">
        function GetSelectedRow(UserLink) {
            var row = UserLink.parentNode.parentNode;
            var rowIndex = row.rowIndex - 1;
            var Userid = row.cells[0].innerHTML;
            alert("RowIndex: " + rowIndex + " Userid : " + Userid + ");
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you this will work, but I need it to work inside of the Document.ready object ... it will not be recognized inside of document ready.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that in your button template column you are using an `Id=UserLink` which will get repeated for each row. Your element id's should be unique. See this [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/127180) for more details.

Your second problem is that `document.getElementById('UserLink');` will actually find the first element with the id of `UserLink` which is always going to be the first row. In your case you can us `var ul = this;` and that should give you the button that was actually clicked.

To summarize:

- I would suggest getting ride of the id on your button or make them unique.
- Change `document.getElementById('UserLink')` to `this` and that will get you the button that was clicked.

Comment: this works, but when I change "document.getElementbyId(this) ... my var is null, eventhough this is showing the correct linkbutton. ... I am think I am close to my answer. Thank you

Comment: so, I took out the document.getElementbyId(this) to  var ul = this; works great!! Thank you so much for your assistance.

Comment: Let me clarify. Don't use `document.getElementById(this)` use `var ul = this;`.

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel, no problem. If you can mark it as the answer so that others may reference it that would be great.